# Error: Duplicate Provider Authority

Tags: google-play-store, updates, system-error

My android phone is asking me to update Google Play Store services, however when I hit update it will stop with the Duplicate Provider Authority error.  Ive noticed that others who had this error with game apps, etc... could just uninstall and reinstall the app, however I cant do that with Google Play Store.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Which phone do you have, and what version of Android is it running? Is it stock, or rooted/custom ROM?

Comment: Are you sure this is a genuine message, and not a scam from a website or a malware app on your phone? "Duplicate Provider Authority" is often a sign that a package is masquerading as a different one. Please describe in more detail how your phone is "asking you to update". Include a screenshot if that helps.